# How to write all JSON objects from a for loop into a text file using java

Tags: java, json, for-loop, text-files

I am trying to save all my results from JSON into a text file. However, my for loop seems to be only saving the last result from the loop to the text file. It is obviously just re-writing the result each time into the file. I want to be able to save all the results from the for loop before it saves the file.

```
    List<Status> statuses = null;
        Query query = new Query("football");
        query.setCount(100);
        query.lang("en");
        int i=0;





         try {     

                QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                ArrayList tweets = new ArrayList();

                for( Status status : result.getTweets()){
                    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
                      String rawJSON = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
                        String statusfile = "results.txt";
                        storeJSON(rawJSON, statusfile);
                        i++;
                }
                System.out.println(i);

              }   
              catch(TwitterException e) {         
                System.out.println("Get timeline: " + e + " Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
              }     

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode() == 88) {
            System.err.println("Rate Limit exceeded!!!!!!");
            try {
                long time = e.getRateLimitStatus().getSecondsUntilReset();
                if (time > 0)
                    Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void storeJSON(String rawJSON, String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        bw.write(rawJSON);
        bw.flush();
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }
        if (osw != null) {
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The method at the bottom called storeJSON is where the work is being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) with append mode ?

```
 private static void storeJSON(String rawJSON, String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try
    {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        fileWriter.write(rawJSON);
        fileWriter.write("\n");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(fileWriter!=null) {
            fileWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```